# How can I load a sound by input value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In the first, I use Firefox. I have code for a HTML spectrum, but I can't load sound from a textbox using input's id and javascript.

This is input:

`<input type="text" id="song" value="first.mp3"></input>`

And this is a part of javascript's code, the other part is for making spectrum:

```
var song = document.getElementById('song').value;
loadSound(song.value);
```

If I use directly values without input, for example `loadSound("first.mp3");`, code work, sound is loaded and it starts to play.

This is my full code, but doesn't run on jsfiddle.net because there is no sound for import: https://jsfiddle.net/77js54b4/.

But how can I make a load sound from input textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using value twice in your example...

var song = document.getElementById('song').**value**;
loadSound(song.**value**);

If `document.getElementById('song').value = "song.mp3"`, then `loadSound(song);` should work according to what you mentioned.

Comment: Ok. It an idea. Not quite what I wanted, but it's acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing! :) Glad I could help.